# Replacing table and renaming primary key - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

To preface, I am trying to replace an entire table with a new table with same columns, but with updated values.

I have the following SQL code:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE "original" RENAME TO "original_old";
ALTER TABLE "original_new" RENAME TO "original";
ALTER TABLE "original" RENAME CONSTRAINT "temp_original_id" to "original_id";
DROP TABLE "original_old";
COMMIT;
```

Output:

```
ERROR:  constraint "temp_original_id" for table "original" does not exist
```

However, if I do the following before the last `ALTER` statement:

```
SELECT * from original;
```

I see `temp_original_id` present in the table.

I can't seem to find any other sources that lead me to updating primary key (at least that worked)

The table I am replacing also has dependencies with other tables.. So I was wondering if this would be a viable solution to even begin with

Comment: `temp_original_id` is a column. You're trying to rename a column, not rename a [constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp) on a column.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `ALTER TABLE "original" RENAME COLUMN "temp_original_id" to "original_id";` ?